# Dropdownlist on change do JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple jquery function that for some reason is not working and I don't see the issue, I just want to change an input text when the dropdownlist selected value changes, the code looks like this, please kindly follow this link:

`plnkr`https://plnkr.co/edit/xojs3NbD1nkXZpii6twt?p=preview

Idea: when the dropdownlist is in blank the input text will be in black too, when dropdownlist has value selected then input will also has a value.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value of input as `html()`. There's not `html` property for input text

```
$("#stateorprovince").val("NY ");
```

And you don't need `$("#borough1 option:selected").val();` to get the selected value. You can do it like this `$("#borough1).val()` .

I've made few changes in your code. Check

```js
$(function () {
$("#borough1").change(function () {
var borough = $(this).val();
if (borough == "") {
$("#stateorprovince").html("");
return false;
}
else {
$("#stateorprovince").val("NY " + $(this).find('option:selected').text());
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Borough</label>
<select id="borough1">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2">Bronx</option>
<option value="3">Brooklyn</option>
<option value="1">Manhattan</option>
<option value="4">Queens</option>
<option value="5">Staten Island</option>
</select>
<td>
<label>State</label>
<input type="text" id="stateorprovince">
</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you, did not see that!

Answer (score 0):

change `html()` to `val()`

```
if (borough == "") {
$("#stateorprovince").val("");
return false;
}
else {
$("#stateorprovince").val("NY ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the mistake!